Subfigures in latex not compiling
I would like to create a subfigure in latex. It won't compile correctly and I cannot understand why. The figures compile individually when simply using figure instead of subfigure. I have included the package subfigure and am using this code in latex:
\begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/TPA.png}
     \caption{TPA}
     \label{fig:TPA}
 \end{subfigure}
 \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/dmt.png}
     \caption{DMT}
     \label{fig:DMT}
 \end{subfigure}
   \centering  
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/bhet.png}
     \caption{BHET}
     \label{fig:BHET}
 \end{subfigure}
    \caption{molecules}
    \label{fig:PET monomers}

\end{figure}
This is the error message:
Missing number, treated as zero.
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
This is how it is compiling:

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Please add a [mre]

Here is an example of code that works correctly.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{subcaption}% Offers an user interface to sub-captions.
\usepackage{float}% Improves the interface for defining floating objects

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Firts subfigure.}
\label{fig:first}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Second subfigure.}
\label{fig:second}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.30\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Third subfigure.}
\label{fig:third}
\end{subfigure}
    
\caption{Creating subfigures in \LaTeX.}
\label{fig:figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

enter image description here
